# Hyperledger Writing your First Application setup

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I follow the link at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html and try to setup the test network. When I run the script `startFabric.sh`, I get the following error on Mac OS:

> Error connecting due to rpc error: code = Unavailable desc= grpc:the connection is unavailable.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Have you followed instructions from https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html?

Comment: @Artem Barger : Yes, I do have all the prerequisites installed.

Comment: Just followed instruction on my mac and everything seemed to work as expected. Try to ask on chat.hyperledger.org, providing more debug info, ppl there will be able to help you.

Comment: @Artem Barger : Thank you,I will do that. When I run the script startFabric.sh, it downloads docker images tagged 1.0.0-rc1. Is that right or should it be 1.0.0?

Comment: @askh: I suppose this should be 1.0.0 now, is they already published and available.

Comment: @Artem Barger : The script goes on to download 1.0.0-rc1. How can I change it so that it downloads 1.0.0.?

Comment: Are you working with latest sources? Can you probably try to ping me over in chat.hyperledger.org? (@C0rWin)

Comment: I suspect that the issue was due to a race condition. The issue may no longer be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that given the timing of this question that you may have run into a race condition with the code and the in-progress release, which was being prepared at this point in time. I suspect that with the advent of the Hyperledger Fabric 1.0.0 release that this problem is resolved.